# SQLAlchemy: обращаться к связанным объектам после закрытия сессии

Tags: python, сессия, orm, sqlalchemy

У меня есть много моделей связанных сами с собой и друг с другом, и эти связи нужно использовать в логике сервера. Код [довольно сложный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1175240/198251), поэтому нельзя сохранять сессии после выполнения запроса. Вместо этого я пытаюсь пред загрузить все объекты:

```py
def db_get_structure():
    with Session(my_engine) as session:
        deps = {x.id: x for x in session.query(Department).all()}
        ...
        return (deps, ...)

def some_logic(id):
    struct = db_get_structure()
    return some_other_logic(struct.deps[id].owner)
```

Однако я получаю следующую ошибку несмотря на то, что все объекты уже подгружены:

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <Department at 0x10476e780> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'owner' cannot proceed

Возможно ли как-то связать загруженные объекты друг с другом так, чтобы использовать их связи после закрытия сессии?

Comment: Почитайте, вроде это про то https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#joined-eager-loading Либо вот это, я не уверен, надо читать, пробовать https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#subquery-eager-loading В любом случае надо смотреть eager loading

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо, видел. Я имел в виду, чтобы обойтись без подзапросов и джоинов, ведь я и так вытащил все записи из БД в объекты Питона положив в словари по ключам. Так-то я их и сам могу оттуда брать (вроде `struct.deps[struct.deps[id].owner_id]`), но думаю, что эту задачу вместе кэшированием должна решать ORM.

Comment: Ну оно же прямо говорит, что сейчас у него lazy load включен и поэтому после закрытия коннекшена оно не может ничего вытащить, у него лапки: `lazy load operation of attribute 'owner' cannot proceed`

Comment: Если включить один из способов `eager loading` по ссылкам вместо `lazy loading`, который действует сейчас судя по ошибке, всё должно получиться как вы хотите.

Comment: @CrazyElf Просто данные *уже* вытещаны и сложены в питонячие объекты `:)` Нужно лишь чтобы они были связаны друг с другом после закрытия сессии, ведь объекты есть, а связей нет; нужен просто какой-нибудь `cached load` вроде моей строки кода выше. Да, `.options(joinedload(` решает, но это ведь и кода больше, и запрос к БД заметно крупнее, хочется более правильное решение найти.

Comment: ... может вам вообще ORM не нужен, раз данных мало ...

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov их *относительно* мало, сотни шт, это немного для того, чтобы хранить полностью в оперативке, но больше, чем было бы удобно для написания своей замены ORM, тем более, полей, связей и разных запросов навалом. Отсюда и вопрос `(:`

Comment: я как раз такую in-memory систему пилю, с пересчетом связей ... но боюсь, что с питоном ее не соединить;